# How can I highlight certain options in a HTML select - using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, coding-style, highlight

I saw this post:

[How can I highlight certain options in a HTML select using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161772)

which is similar to what I need to do, except a bit too complicated for my understanding.  In the html body, I have a dynamically changing select form.  The user can select multiple items from this form, and click a button ("Display") to run a javascript function.  This function already goes through the list to determine which ones have been selected and uses the information somewhere else.

I would like it so that when the user clicks "Display", the items that were selected will be highlighted (and each with a specific color).

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  I figured it out.

```
myList.options[i].style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```